# Custom sound push notification

Tags: java, ios, swift, push-notification

I am receiving notification payload as

```
    [AnyHashable("jsonData"): {"packageName":"com.company.appName","appName":"AppName","orderId":"0","workflow":"PAGE_OWNER_STATUS_WORKFLOW"}, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "You have received a new Order! ";
        title = Orders;
    };
    sound = default;
},AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.jsonData"): {"packageName":"com.company.appName","appName":"AppName","orderId":"0","workflow":"PAGE_OWNER_STATUS_WORKFLOW"}, AnyHashable("title"): Orders, AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 34781329473, AnyHashable("body"): You have received a new Order! , AnyHashable("sound"): phone_ringing.caf, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1597347128946557]
```

It does not add sound name in aps alert. Will it be done from backend?
We are using JAVA for Backend.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the sound property has to be set as a property of the `aps` and not of the `alert` object, like you're receiving now and like it is specified in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification). Apple example:

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “badge” : 9
      “sound” : “bingbong.aiff”
   },
   “messageID” : “ABCDEFGHIJ”
}
```

You should specify the string "default" to play the default notification sound, otherwise a filename must be set and the file needs to exist on the app. These changes would have to be done on the server side.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just wanted to know whether it could be done on mobile side or server side